# (SOLVED) Need form results to only display after valid input, otherwise empty

Tags: php, html

I am very new to PHP, SQL and HTML in general and have only been learning for about 3 months. I am hoping someone can help me - I am just wanting my form to only display the results table if a valid search has been submitted - and only display the results from the database that match the search term.

HTML Code:

```
  <table class="dbtable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Product Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <th>Manufacturer</th>
             <th>Description</th>
             <th>Price</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
        ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?= $product["PRODUCTNAME"] ?> </td>
            <td><?= $product["MANUFACTURER"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $product["DESCRIPTION"] ?></td> 
            <td><?= $product["PRICE"] ?></td> 
            </tr>
        <?php }
        ?>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
require_once "queryDb.php";

$search =["search"];

if (isset($_GET["product"]))
{
$search = $_GET['product'];
}
else 
{
$search = "";
}

$products = getProducts($_GET["product"]);

?>
```

This has now been solved.
Without a value between "" the whole table was returned by default. after adding a value this is now fixed.

Comment: Try something like this: https://3v4l.org/NoHkF

Comment: Thanks Chris, for some reason when the page loads the entire table is still showing. I am hoping for the table to be empty until a user performs a search

Comment: When the page loads and the table shows, is there a query string parameter in the URL?

Comment: Hi Chris, no there isn't. the page simply loads as /camping.php

Is there a way I can force a query string parameter to load with the page? if i search "+" for example this achieves what I want.

Comment: thanks so much chris. this is now solved ...

its because i had $search as an empty string which returned the whole table by default.
after adding a value between "" it is now working as intended :)

Answer (score 0):

Call `getProducts` function in if condition

```
if (isset($_GET["product"]))
{
  $search = $_GET['product'];
  $products = getProducts($search);
}
else
{
  You can return null or some message to display
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shoshana, for some reason when the page loads the entire table is still showing. I am hoping for the table to be empty until a user performs a search